# Aligning one container to the right side of the screen and other to the left side

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I need to have two Containers, one aligned to the right side and other to the left side of the screen.

```
home: Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.teal,
      body: SafeArea(
          child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            width: double.infinity,
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: Container(
              width: 100.00,
              color: Colors.red,
              child: Container(
                width: 100.00,
                color: Colors.blue,
```

Currently, I have a Container aligned to the right side of the screen:

```
child: Container(
              width: 100.00,
              color: Colors.red,
```

. However, I can't find a way to align a second Container to the other side of the screen:

```
child: Container(
                width: 100.00,
                color: Colors.blue,
```

Comment: Use a Row widget

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter Row main axis alignment not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54400525/flutter-row-main-axis-alignment-not-working)